# Random RDP Disconnects

Tags: remote-desktop, event-log, windows-10-v1909

Since my last windows update (Feature update 1909 - not sure if the update is related to the issue), I'm having issues with my rdp session being interrupted several times a day. The computer I'm connecting from is on the same local network.

What makes this issues so frustrating is the fact the when the session disconnects, windows is logged out, which is essentially the same as rebooting, because all unsaved documents are lost. This happens while the rdp session is active. The screen freezes, and in a short time this error is displayed.

[image: error message]

To be clear; a normal disconnect does not sign off of windows. So if I close the session normally, and 
reconnect, all my apps are still open.

I've try searching google, and have looked through the event viewer, but I don't really know what to look for.

**Can anyone help me know what to check next?**

Comment: The next time this happens, note the time. When you next connect, look at the Event Viewer (`eventvwr.msc`) and look for relevant events around that time. Some possible event IDs to keep an eye out for are 1074, 6006, 6008, 4647.

Comment: I did see an event 1000 that says dwm.exe had an error.

Comment: dwm.exe is the service that "draws" windows in, well, Windows. Its job is to make applications windows appear, refresh, resize and close when asked. If for some reason this service hangs, freezes or crashes, then you're in trouble. That's why your RDP session isn't closed. It's just the RDP client window that has a problem. You could run "sfc /scannow" in the command line on your own PC and wait for the result, and/or check in services.msc what instructions "dwm.exe" has when crashing ("do nothing", "restart") for three consecutive crashes. If you can (must be admin), set "restart" on all 3.

Comment: I have the same issue! I have tried looking through the event log but can't pinpoint anything specific.